# Is possible to create a ruby-on-rails migration from a database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, migration, schema

From a previsou existent schema, using modeling tools like mySQL Workbench, The the current database schema is changed.

Is somehow possible for ruby to compare these 2 schemas (before and after modification) and create a propper migration based on these changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could generate the 'new version' schema by pointing a copy of your app to the new db, then run db:schema:dump.  Then run a "diff" on the old vs new schema - keeping only the parts that changed.  Then use some regex-replacements in your editor (or awk) to change the actions to add_column operations, and put those changes into a migration.

At this point, you still need to change your models, controllers, and views to reflect the db-changes.  The diff could be handy for walking through those changes, as well.